# Записать данные с формы в модальном окне в массив и передать в php файл

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Возможно я просто не полностью понимаю как это должно работать. 
у меня есть форма, для создания юзера, в этой форме есть модальное окно, и в нем есть форма, нужно считать данные из формы в модальном окне, и передать их в массив, что бы потом вывести в главной форме (уже введенные данные)

модальное окно:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalConsultTime" tabindex="-1" 
role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalConsultTime" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-content md-modal">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Виберiть час</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="time_start" class="col-md-3 col-sm-5 label-text-company">
                                    Виберiть початкову дату:
                                </label>
                                <div class='input-group date col-md-5 col-sm-6' id='datetimepicker6'>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="time_start" id="time_start"
                                           value="{{old('time_start')}}"/>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span
                                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="time_end" class="col-md-3 col-sm-5 label-text-company">
                                    Виберiть кiнцеву дату:
                                </label>
                                <div class='input-group date col-md-5 col-sm-6' id='datetimepicker7'>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="time_end" id="time_end"
                                           value="{{old('time_end')}}"/>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span
                                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить изменения</button>
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                        </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

функция в контроллере *ConsultsController.php* :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $consult = new Consult();
    return redirect('sconsult');
}
```

Извините если вопрос не коректен, первый раз пишу его , ибо уже несколько дней не могу сделать эту простейшую задачу.

Answer (score 0):

HTML-формы (GET и POST) ¶
Когда происходит отправка данных формы PHP-скрипту, информация из этой формы автоматически становится доступной ему. Существует несколько способов получения этой информации, например:

Пример #1 Простая HTML-форма

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
    Имя:  <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправь меня!" />
</form>
```

С версии PHP 5.4.0, есть только два способа получить доступ к данным из форм HTML. Доступные сейчас способы приведены ниже:

Пример #2 Доступ к данным из простой HTML-формы, отправленной через POST

```
<?php
echo $_POST['username'];
echo $_REQUEST['username'];
?>
```

[Тут много всего](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=examples&page=069)

более детально тут - [Клик сюда](http://php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.forms.php%22%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%A2%20%D0%9E%D0%9D%D0%9E%22)
Либо же тут - [либо же сюда](http://php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.forms.php)
Или сюда нажми - [Самое доступное описание тут](http://php720.com/lesson/44)

Comment: это все я знаю, спасибо, только мне нужно сделать, что бы при добавлении времени (  в модальном окне) , оно закрывалось, и страница не  обновлялась, а данные были записаны в массив, или обьект, и были выведены в первой форме, что бы потом уже можно было это все сохранить...

Comment: у меня, так сказать. форма в форме

Comment: советую эту задачу разделить на подзадачи, и по каждой отдельно найти свой ответ, а потом их уже скомпилить

Comment: спасибо) попробую решить ее таким способом )

Comment: вместо `POST` и `REQUEST`, наверное, лучше использовать встроенный Request

Comment: @StereoFlo да, это будет более удобно)  но я решила сделать вариант проще)  но пока еще не доделала )